# Transforming less frequent values

Tags: knime

Suppose I have the following columns for a csv that I read through a 'File Reader' node:

```
id, name, city, income
```

After reading it, I notice that the column 'city' contains a huge number of unique values. I want to:

1. Know which values are the 'k' most frequent for 'city'
2. Modify those which are not the 'k' most frequent to hold something like 'other'

Example:

```
id, name, city, income
1, Person 1, New York, 100.000 
2, Person 2, Toronto, 90.000
3, Person 3, New York, 50.000
4, Person 4, Seattle, 60.000
```

Choosing k to be 1, I want to produce the following table:

```
id, name, city, income
1, Person 1, New York, 100.000 
2, Person 2, Other, 90.000
3, Person 3, New York, 50.000
4, Person 4, Other, 60.000
```

It happens because 'New York' is the '1' most frequent value for 'city' in the original table.

Do you know how I can do that using Knime?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSV Reader to read the data. With the Statistics and Row Filter nodes you can find the k most frequent values. From those, you can create a collection cell using GroupBy. With that collection value, you can use Rule Engine with a similar ruleset:

```
$city$ IN $most frequent cities$ => $city$
TRUE => "Other"
```